# Issue with timing being removed when sent over socket

Tags: java, sockets, object, time

I have a game set up where I send an array of Tower and Troop objects across a socket between a server and a client and for some reason the attack rate and animation (which leads me to believe the timing properties) are being ignored/edited. Here is the tower class:

```
package jandek.towers;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import jandek.handler.Handler;
import jandek.main.Frame;
import jandek.main.Game;
import jandek.utils.Utils;


public abstract class Tower implements Serializable{

private int range;
private double attackDMG;
private double attackSPEED; //1 = 1/60 seconds
private byte[][][] image;
private int x;
private int y;
private long lastAttackTime;
private int multiplier;
private int level; //0 = 1;
private boolean moving;
private boolean rangeNeedsToBeDrawn;
private int width = 32;
private int height = 32;
//private BufferedImage[][][] bufferedImages = new BufferedImage[16][4][2];
private ArrayList<Integer> troopsInTroopsArrayThatAreInRange;
private int animationFrame = 0;
private int animationFrameSpeed = 60; //nano seconds between changes
private double animationFrameLastChange; //last change
boolean attacked;
boolean animation = false;
/**
 * 
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param level
 * @param multiplier
 * @param range
 * @param attackDMG
 * @param attackSPEED
 * @param image
 */
public Tower(int x, int y, int level, int multiplier, int range, double attackDMG, double attackSPEED, byte[][][] image){
    troopsInTroopsArrayThatAreInRange = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.range = range;
    this.attackDMG = attackDMG + (level * multiplier);
    this.attackSPEED = attackSPEED;
    this.image = image;
    this.level = level;
    this.multiplier = multiplier;
    lastAttackTime = Handler.getGame().getTime();
    moving = false;
    rangeNeedsToBeDrawn = true;

}
public void update(){
    attacked = false;
    if(moving == true){
        setX(Frame.getMouseX());
        setY(Frame.getMouseY());
    }
    AttackTarget();
    if(attacked){
        animation = true;
        animationFrameLastChange = Handler.getGame().getTime();
        animationFrame = 1;
        //Handler.getGame().getLogWriter().write("Animation is at the second image");
    }

    if(animation && Handler.getGame().getTime() - animationFrameLastChange >= animationFrameSpeed){
        animationFrame = 0;
        animation = false;
        }
}

private void AttackTarget(){
    if((Handler.getGame().getTime() - lastAttackTime) > attackSPEED && !moving){
        for(int i = 0; i < Handler.getTroops().size() ; i++){
            int x1 = this.x + this.width / 2;
            int y1 = this.y + this.height / 2;
            int x2 = Handler.getTroops().get(i).getX() + Handler.getTroops().get(i).getSize() / 2;
            int y2 = Handler.getTroops().get(i).getY() + Handler.getTroops().get(i).getSize() / 2;
            if(Utils.getDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) <= range){
                troopsInTroopsArrayThatAreInRange.add(i);
                attacked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(attacked){
        Handler.getGame().getLogWriter().write("");
        Handler.getGame().getLogWriter().write(Handler.getGame().getTime() - lastAttackTime + " : " + attackSPEED);
        lastAttackTime = Handler.getGame().getTime();
        Handler.getGame().getLogWriter().write(Handler.getGame().getTime() - lastAttackTime + " : " + attackSPEED);
        Handler.getGame().getLogWriter().write("");
        double min = range;
        int nearestTroop = -1;
        for(int j = 0; j < troopsInTroopsArrayThatAreInRange.size(); j++){
            int x1 = this.x + this.width / 2;
            int y1 = this.y + this.height / 2;
            int x2 = Handler.getTroops().get(troopsInTroopsArrayThatAreInRange.get(j)).getX() + Handler.getTroops().get(troopsInTroopsArrayThatAreInRange.get(j)).getSize() / 2;
            int y2 = Handler.getTroops().get(troopsInTroopsArrayThatAreInRange.get(j)).getY() + Handler.getTroops().get(troopsInTroopsArrayThatAreInRange.get(j)).getSize() / 2;
            if(Utils.getDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) < min){
                min = Utils.getDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            //  Handler.getGame().getLogWriter().write("troop distance checked");   
                nearestTroop = troopsInTroopsArrayThatAreInRange.get(j);
            }
        }
        Handler.getTroops().get(nearestTroop).changeHealth(-(int)attackDMG);
        troopsInTroopsArrayThatAreInRange.clear();
    }


}

}
```

the update method is called in a run method that runs at 60 times a second, and Handler.getGame().getTime() is incremented in the same run method. Here is the log from Handler.getGame().getLogWriter():

```
505
506
507
508
509
510
511
512
513
514
515
516
517
518
519
520

206 : 120.0
0 : 120.0

521

207 : 120.0
0 : 120.0

522
523
524
525
526
527
528
529
530
531
532
533
534
535
536
537
538
539
540
541
542
543
544
545
546
547
548
549
550
551
552
553
554
555
556
```

Each "1" above is printed out at the end of the run method, thus showing that

`Handler.getGame().getTime() - lastAttackTime`

is somehow being disturbed via the socket. Any ideas? I hope I'm not missing something overly obvious or simple.

edit for socket code:

```
private void updateConnection(){
        if(isClientActive()){
            if(player.getType() == 0){
                client.sendObjects(towers);
            }else{
                client.sendObjects(troops);
            }
            ArrayList<Object> obj = (ArrayList<Object>)client.receiveObjects();
            if(obj != null && obj.size() > 0){
                if (obj.get(0) instanceof Troop) {
                    mendTroops(obj);
                }else if(obj.get(0) instanceof Troop){
                    mendTowers(obj);
                }
            }else{
                if(player.getType() == 0){
                    troops.clear();
                }else{
                    towers.clear();
                }
            }
        }else if(isServerActive()){
            if(player.getType() == 0){
                server.sendObjects(towers);
            }else{
                server.sendObjects(troops);
            }
            ArrayList<Object> obj = (ArrayList<Object>)server.receiveObjects();
            if(obj != null && obj.size() > 0){
                if (obj.get(0) instanceof Troop) {
                    mendTroops(obj);
                }else if(obj.get(0) instanceof Tower){
                    mendTowers(obj);
                }
            }else{
                if(player.getType() == 0){
                    troops.clear();
                }else{
                    towers.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What socket? There is no sockets code here.

Comment: I'm not going to wade through that wall of code to figure out how you calculate times, but if it depends on the system clocks being synchronized, and you don't have the systems using NTP to set their clocks, then all bets are off.  For better help, reduce your code to the simplest example that reproduces the issue.  You don't yet know what the problem is, you've just made a leap from a symptom (attack rate not what you expect) to a cause (timing is being discarded) which is likely unjustified.  The process of reducing the code will probably reveal the real problem.

Comment: I know it is sustained within the update() method (more precisely the attack() method) in towers. I use a run method that runs at 60 fps and is stored in a variable accessed statically by the tower object. The client and server do not have to be in sync, as they both use the same run method and start at the same time. I had the attack rate working fine until I added the socket system into the game, so I know it has some correlation with that.

Comment: your problem is located in sending the data (and receiving the data); so you have to print out the data that are sent (on the sending side) and the data that are received(from the receiver) - and compare - then locate the ptoblem - I already saw you are using some fancy methods such as writeUnshared() - for a beginner it sounds you are mixed

Comment: Where do you see writeUnshared? And yes, the issue was that the array of towers received is not changing its lastAttackTime, it's at what ever it is initialized with. I'm uncertain if it is all its properties or none, but it is strange. I'll try playing around with how the arrays are updated between the server and client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any sockets code in your post, but neither TCP nor UDP offers any timing guarantees. TCP uses buffering extensively for purposes of coalescing outgoing writes into smaller numbers of wire segments. You can mitigate this a bit by disabling the Nagle algorithm, but you are never going to get real-time performance out of any network.

Comment: Ok, so what would be the best way to have a program run on two computers that send objects between them that need to use something such as attack speed? Also, does it matter that the time is being checked statically?

Comment: You would have to send the speed as part of your data, or the time origins and deltas, instead of relying on zero or fixed network latency, or for that matter on the time difference between the computers being either zero or a fixed quantity.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by speed? Do you mean I should keep a current game time reference in the tower object?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison Surely you jest? In what way is 'never' not an answer?

Comment: @Dak31 There isn't enough information here about your application to answer that, but you will have to get rid of the assumption that packet sending time = packet arrival time, or that there is zero latency, or a fixed latency, or zero time drift, or a fixed time drift. You will have to redesign what you're sending in such a way that time is explicit, not implicit.